# jQuery function to move a div left/right when clicking another div

Tags: jquery

Yes, this sounds like a simple question, and it probably is. But when i am implementing some of the solutions I an finding, not of them are working.

Basically I have a main content div and behind that div I have a small sidebar div that I would like to animate out from behind the main div when i click on an element. Seems simple? Well my head can't quite code it right.. Also, jQuery noob here if we are going to be completely honest:

Here is the relevent HTML:

```
        <div id="clickme" style="z-index: 900; background-color:Black; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>

    <div id="superMain">
        <div id="leftFlyout"></div>
        <div class="main"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/></div>
        <div id="rightFlyout"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#rightFlyout
{
width: 75px;
height: 400px;
background-color: Red;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 875px;

}

#leftFlyout
{
float:left;
width: 75px;
height: 400px;
background-color: Red;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 10px;

}

#superMain
{
position:relative;
}
.main
{
border-left:1px solid black;
border-right:1px solid black;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
padding: 0px;
padding-top: 10px;
margin: 0px auto;
min-height: 420px;
height:auto;
width: 940px;
background-color: White;
z-index: 10;
}
```

annnnnnd, the jQuery (the whole header in case i messed that up too somehow)

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<script>
    $('#clickme').toggle(function () {

        $('#rightFlyout').animate({
            left: '+=200'
        }, 458, 'swing', function () {

            // Animation complete. CALLBACK?

        });

    }, function () {

        $('#leftFlyout').animate({
            left: '-=200'
        }, 458, 'swing', function () {

            // Animation complete. CALLBACK?

        });

    });
</script>
</head>
```

Please help! And if it is a ridiculously dumb mistake I am making, please mock relentlessly.

Comment: What isn't working with this code?

Comment: That's the question of the day Blender. I am running it and clicking on the div and nothing is happening..

Comment: Did you forget to use the $(document).ready() construct?

Comment: @alpacalipsnao Ha! Man, I knew I was doing something idiotic. Thanks a bunch! -100 points for me, +1000 for you.

Comment: Uh.. Is there a way to accept a comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$(document).ready()` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an absolute position (including 'px') in the `left=` property:

```
...
$('#leftFlyout').animate({
        left: '-200px'
    }, 458, ...
```

And also, your code says:

if I click `clickMe` move `rightFlyout` 200px right.
if I click again, move `leftFlyout` 200px left.
if I click `clickMe` move `rightFlyout` 200px right.
and so on.

If you want to move one of these and restore the other to the original position, you will have to add the code to restore it at each function (the toggle doesn't restores the changes of the called functions).

Comment: I tried that and I am still not getting anything. Is it possible I am not referencing the jQuery file correctly? I get intellisense so i don't think so.  Totally stumped

Comment: well now that I got it moving I see the problem you were referring to. Can you elaborate a bit on the solution to this? How can I toggle something back and forth?

Comment: nevermind, it is actually working fine if i just set the target div to be the same on each action. Toggles no probelm